# sendRedirect to another domain not working in Appfuse application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, appfuse

I have created a new Appfuse 2.1.0 struts2 application and from the servlet i want to redirect to **https://gmail.com**, i have used the following code:
                   *response.sendRedirect("https://gmail.com");*

But this line was not working, my application was not redirecting to this domain which i have specified. Do i need to do any configurations to redirect to another domain from my appfuse application?

Comment: And what does it do instead of redirecting? Any exception? What's the stack trace? And what's the code behind it?

Comment: Much depends on what you do after the 'line that is not working'. Please provide more code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: There is no exceptions, just an empty page was displayed and in the address bar the servlet URL was displayed. And in the doGet method of servlet, there are only 2 lines of code, _'sendRedirect()'_ and next _'return'_ statement

Answer (score -1):

You need to give Url like:

```
  response.sendRedirect("https:www.gmail.com");
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that.